# PHP Accessing API in external server

Tags: php, api, curl

I am running a server which runs main website e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com and another server which holds all APIs lets say. http://api.mywebsite.com. Both of these are built using different technologies.

What I currently do is make a cURL calls to access data from APIs from api.mywebsite.com on www.mywebsite.com but its going very heavy on page response times on www.mywebsite.com.

So I am planning for an alternative a library or something which can help to make similar calls but with lesser resource consumption.

PS: I make GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests to server so can't use something that only provides GET.

Comment: Have you *profiled* what exactly is taking the time? Is it the curl library, or simply the network roundtrip?

Comment: Yes its cURL library which is causing the mayhem earlier I was having direct db connection and every thing was working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you access the data directly off the database? 

Have you tried caching with MemCache or Redis?

Comment: I don't want to access data directly from DB. I have API layer which performs several tasks.

Comment: If that's the case the best option would be using redis or memcache to store data into RAM for instant access and reduced response time.

Comment: Thanks I am going to use Redis.